# How compare value of cells in excel then print result to other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a very long table in this format:

```
Table:
B  | C | D | 
----------------
c10|mnp|   |
------------
c12|abc|dif|
------------
c15|xyz|   |
------------
c17|abc|equ|
------------
c17|mnp|   |
------------
c18|abc|dif|
------------
c19|xyz|   |
------------
c21|uck|   |
------------
c25|qkj|   |
------------
c25|abc|equ|
------------
c26|npk|   |
------------
```

The code in my normal understanding is like this:

```
FOR (whole Sheet or whole range of C column ($C$1:$C$8000) )
    IF $C(i) = "abc" then
      IF (($B(i) == $B(i-1)) OR (($B(i) == $B(i+1))
      THEN:
           assign value $D(i) = "equ"
      ELSE
           assign value $D(i) = "dif"
```

It is quite straight forward in normal programming language but I really don't know is it possible to code that in excel and how to execute that code ? My table is really very long and I can not do it manually!

Comment: check documentation on this functions: [IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx), [OR](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/or-HP005209209.aspx), [Nested IF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php)

Comment: I think the documentation suggested is not enough cases to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I mean I don't know what language could be used in excel and how is its format. How to run that code also. This I think cannot solved by putting in the formula bar alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple formula to use Column D, then you can just enter this in D2 and then drag down to autofill `=IF(C2="abc",IF(OR(B1=B2,B3=B2),"equ","dif"),"")` @simoco makes a great point that you should check out the available documentation prior to posting here as this site is intended to help solve problems after you have tried things out first.

Comment: It was great suggestion of dragging the cell, in a moment my mind is get blank of that solution !! What a perfect solution! Btw, could you suggest me how to fill color for the whole row if its cell equal "equal" please ?

Comment: I would use conditional formatting to do that. Here is a [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) on how to apply conditional formatting using a formula. Please don't forget to mark the question as answered!

Comment: If I drag, there will be many cell with "FALSE" value. Can we replace "FALSE" with blank cells ?

Comment: That is what my formula does. If the value in C is not "abc" then it will display "".

Comment: Then the text "equ" or "dif" is not searchable isn't it ? All the cells we drag will be the same format and if I want to count the number of "equ" or "dif" will return the same value, and it is the total number of cells that I dragged. (I counted by using replace function and replace it with the same text, when done, it show how many replacements and I see the result always the same for what ever text).

Comment: This is not a way using a formula to leave a cell completely blank. You either need to work on a macro which does the same thing the formula I provided does, or use a formula like this to count the equ/dif values: `=COUNTIF(D2:D20,"equ")+COUNTIF(D2:D20,"dif")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable help, much appreciate!